# Timeout Connection not working properly - Java

Tags: java, timeout, timeoutexception

I have a code that connects to a balance, using java socket. The problem is that the connection timeout parameter isn't working properly. No matter what parameter is passed, my waiting time is always 24 seconds.

Is there some sort of parameter on the server I should change?

Here's the part of the code that might interest you.

```
    int TimeOutConnectionMs = TimeOutConnection.intValue() * 1000;

    socket = new Socket();

    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, portNumber.intValue()) , TimeOutConnection.intValue() * 1000);
```

The exceptions used are the following

```
  } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    msgException = e.getMessage();
    logMessage(process, "EXCEPTION", niveauLog.intValue(), "SocketTimeoutException: " + msgException, host + "_" + portNumber);

  } catch (java.net.SocketException e) {
    msgException = e.getMessage();
    logMessage(process, "EXCEPTION", niveauLog.intValue(), "java net Socket Exception: " + msgException, host + "_" + portNumber);

  } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
    msgException = e.getMessage();
    logMessage(process, "EXCEPTION", niveauLog.intValue(), "java net Unknown Host Exception: " + msgException, host + "_" + portNumber);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: from where you import `TimeOutConnection`? are you using **`int`** `Value` not `initValue`... are you aware of this?

Comment: @JordiCastilla TimeOutConnection is a parameter i'm receiving from my PLSQL code, and i'm using intValue() yes, what's the differnece.

Comment: don't know, I want to check the API of the class to know what the method does, i think this will explain why 24 seconds and which method use to achieve your goal

Comment: It's the socket class, details are here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score -1):

You are multiplying by 1000 twice, so your actual connect timeout is 1000 times what you think it is.

Comment: No i'm not, the first one is TimeOutConnectionMs ( used later for smthg else ), and the other one is simply TimeOutConnection

Comment: So if it isn't relevant why post it and cause confusion? And y not use it, as  it's there, instead of computing the same thing twice?